# Disable text selection but allow cut, copy, and paste

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, clipboard

This is for a list component which allows you to select, cut, copy, paste, and drag and drop to rearrange list items. The problem is that `user-select: none` in Chrome appears to disable cut, copy, and paste events, even if its applied to the children and not the parent.

I have created the following JSFiddle which reproduces the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/c1n4vv7j/10/

```
<div tabindex="0" oncut="alert('hello')">
    <li>Click Here and Hit CTRL+X</li>
    <li>Works in Firefox and Edge but not Chrome!</li>
</div>
```

If you follow the instructions you should see a popup in Firefox and Edge, but not Chrome 61. The only workaround I found so far is to create a <li> at the top that has a 1px height and have the onclick event select that, then the <ul> can still continue to receive clipboard events. This solution is undesirable, and neither is allowing the text on the elements to be selected.

I am starting to be convinced that this might actually be a bug in Chrome and that it does not conform to the HTML5 Clipboard spec which says that the events should still fire even if there isn't something selected, just that there's a focused node.

Anyone know a nice workaround or should I report this to Chrome?

**Edit:**

If you change the cut handler to show us the activeElement, it reports the div, while the event target reports body:

```
$("*").on("cut", function(event){
  console.log(event.target);
  console.log(document.activeElement);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont use user-select: none.

I hope this helps you

```
div > li{
-webkit-user-select: auto;
-moz-user-select: auto;
-ms-user-select: auto;
user-select: auto;
}

div > li::selection {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0); //you can use transparent also
}
```

for firefox

```
div > li::selection {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0); //you can use transparent also
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but D&D is required, and setting `draggable="true"` in Chrome automatically adds `user-select: none` to <li> from the user-agent stylesheet.

Comment: make the user-select to auto in chrome

Comment: I don't like this solution because it messes with the default select behavior rather than simply disabling it. Ideally I'd prefer to use user-select: none; and not have to worry about whether draggable adds it or not. So while this solution does work, it's not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

The event is fired, just not on the node that you were expecting. The event was fired on `<body>` instead on your `<div>`: https://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/c1n4vv7j/12/

The spec does state that:

> To fire a clipboard event of type e,
>
> 1. Let clear-was-called be false
> 2. Let types-to-clear be an empty list
> 3. Let clipboard-entry be the sequence number of the current clipboard content, or null if the OS clipboard does not support sequence numbers
> 4. Let trusted be true if the event is generated by the user agent, false otherwise
> 5. Set target as follows:
>
>    - If the context is editable:
>
>      - Let target be the element that contains the start of the selection in document order, or the body element if there is no selection or cursor.
>    - Else, if the context is not editable
>
>      - Let target be the focused node, or the body element if no node has focus.

I believe it is a "bug" since the node did receive a `focus` event but not the `cut` event, but keep in mind that the `user-select` property is still a draft and not a standard.

Comment: That's exactly the part that I saw, so yes I believe that kind of confirms it as a bug. The focused node should have been the target, and we can clearly see it is the focused node because of the blue outline when we click on it. First I'm going to report it... but still looking for some way of working around it....

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to add custom selection behavior in table cells, maintaining the ability to copy and paste. Since using `user-select: none` generates a buggy behavior in Firefox, I solved using the `selection` pseudo-element, removing the default text selection:

```css
    table td::selection {
      background: none;
    }
```